# PostgreSQL Syntax error, can't find it

Tags: postgresql, syntax

I have a code which creates 6 templates, adds data to them, merges them and export it as data. I can make it work by using F5 on different paragraphs, but I want to make the whole code work. Can someone help me, I am pretty new.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE john1
(email VARCHAR(200));

COPY john1(email) from 'E:\WORK\FXJohn1.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER

CREATE TEMP TABLE john2
(email VARCHAR(200));

COPY john2(email) from 'E:\WORK\FXJohn2.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER

CREATE TEMP TABLE john3
(email VARCHAR(200));

COPY john3(email) from 'E:\WORK\FXJohn3.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER

CREATE TEMP TABLE john4
(email VARCHAR(200));

COPY john4(email) from 'E:\WORK\FXJohn4.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER

CREATE TEMP TABLE john5
(email VARCHAR(200));

COPY john5(email) from 'E:\WORK\FXJohn5.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER

CREATE TEMP TABLE john6
(email VARCHAR(200));

COPY john6(email) from 'E:\WORK\FXJohn6.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER

CREATE TABLE finished AS
(SELECT * FROM john1
UNION
SELECT * FROM john2
UNION
SELECT * FROM john3
UNION
SELECT * FROM john4
UNION
SELECT * FROM john5
UNION
SELECT * FROM john6);

DO $func$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE $$
    COPY public."finished" TO 'E:\$$ || to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY_MM_DD') || $$.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
  $$;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

@Rupert

Sorry, but for some reason this script is not running for me, I get this error:

```html
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "for" LINE 1: for x in $(ls FXJohn1*.csv);
```

```
           Do I change the variables correctly?
```

```html
for x in $(ls file_name*.csv);
```

| I  change file_name to one of my .csv in the folder|

```html
do psql -c "copy table_name from
```

| I change table_name to my current table name I've created|

```html
'/path/.   todir/$x' csv" db_name; done
```

| I change path to E:\WORK (there are my all my csv files.

Comment: I think you miss a semicolon (`;`) at the end of `COPY` commands.

Comment: no, I already tried that at first...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can load multiple .csv files into the same table. So let's set that up first:

```
CREATE TABLE finished 
(
email varchar(200)
)
```

Then you can load multiple files from the same folder using a simple bash script:

```
for x in $(ls file_name*.csv); 
do psql -c "copy table_name from
'/path/.   todir/$x' csv" db_name; done
```

This saves you doing multiple 'copies' and then the multiple UNIONs.

Then you can run your script:

```
DO $func$
BEGIN
EXECUTE $$
COPY public."finished" TO 'E:\$$ ||     to_char(CURRENT_DATE,
'YYYY_MM_DD') || $$.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
$$;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Sorry, but for some reason this script is not running for me, I get this error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "for" LINE 1: for x in $(ls FXJohn1*.csv); 

Do I change the variables correctly?:

for x in $(ls file_name*.csv);

| I change file_name to one of my .csv in the folder|

do psql -c "copy table_name from

| I change table_name to my current table name I've created|

'/path/.   todir/$x' csv" db_name; done
 
| I change path to E:\WORK (there are my all my csv files.

Comment: Firstly, this is a bash script so I believe the syntax error is from the fact you have ran this in psql! So remember to run this script in the terminal, as it connects to psql itself. Secondly, in the first line change John1 to just John (this way the script will load any file prefixed 'John'. Then change file_name to the root, so 'E:\WORK\*'. Then try that :)

Comment: I managed to connect to terminal, but I still get this error. https://ibb.co/jd4Xqd What is wrong with it?

Comment: You need to run the script in the command line not in psl that's all.